# Linux - No module named pythoncom

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, linux, django

**How to install pythoncom on Debian server?**

I'm connecting to a Microsoft Server which has Microsoft SQL installed in it. My server is Linux- Debian. I'm using Django to connect to the MS SQL server. When I try to connect it to the MS SQL server, it returns `No module named pythoncom` error. I've looked onto various SO threads but they all recommend to install active python which is for windows not for linux.

Here are my  django Settings.

```
'a_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado', 
        'NAME': 'data_AutoScale',  
        'USER': 'Scale_Admin',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': '10.***.***.*',
        'PORT': '',            
    }
```

**how do I solve this problem?**

Comment: I think you can try using django-pyodbc ... This will help you in establishing connection to MS Sql server. More details about usage can be found here: code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/

Comment: You can't. `pythoncom` is part of PyWin32, which rules out Linux. Use `django-pyodbc` instead of `django-mssql`

Comment: I tried installing, django-odbc and pyodbc as well, and change the Database settings as well, now there's an error saying `No module named hashcompat`, and upon searching it seems that hashcompat was removed from Django-1.6 and I'm using Django-1.6. S, how can I connect to MS-SQL ??? Please help.